# Error: No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add"

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic cordova angular.
I am getting the following below error while run the command

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```

after executing the several command, it display the below errors.

```
adding android to cordova.platforms array in package.json
No scripts found for hook "after_platform_add".
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd platform add android --verbose exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: 'process.exit' received +0ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: running 1 functions +2ms
  ionic:utils-process error while killing process tree for 11004: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 11004 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "11004" not found.
  ionic:utils-process
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 11004 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +90ms
  ionic:utils-process onBeforeExit handler: error from function: Error: Command failed: taskkill /pid 11004 /T /F
  ionic:utils-process ERROR: The process "11004" not found.
  ionic:utils-process
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:390:12)
  ionic:utils-process     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
  ionic:utils-process     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
  ionic:utils-process     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
  ionic:utils-process   killed: false,
  ionic:utils-process   code: 128,
  ionic:utils-process   signal: null,
  ionic:utils-process   cmd: 'taskkill /pid 11004 /T /F'
  ionic:utils-process } +2ms
  ionic:utils-process processExit: exiting (exit code: 1) +7ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at your `config.xml` and delete a line looking like
`<hook src="[link to a script]" type="after_platform_add" />`

Then you can run `platform add android --verbose` so it will show you the exact path of the remaining scripts.